# How does Spring create the base URL for a Maven project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I'm using Eclipse and I'm learning Spring MVC/Rest/Security.

I created a Maven project from scratch but for some reason unknown to me, it refuses to connect to the database.

Then I used a sample project I have from somewhere, but replaced basically every file in it with the ones of the new project. For some miraculous reason this one DOES work even though it's comparably the same as the first one.

But I do have a problem with it: Whenever I try to run this project, under the "Run on server" window, Eclipse shows me the project as

Configured:
new-project-name(original-project-name)

When it manages to run (because it takes forever to load and it sometimes times out), the url given is:

```
localhost:8080/original-project-name/
```

instead of the new name I have given. I have replace the original project name in every file I could think of. In the folders that contain it, in "pom.xml" of course, "pom.properties", ".project", ".classpath" and even a eclipse config file called "org.eclipse.wst.common.component", to no avail.

I cannot find what file is it reading it from and I have checked every single one. I think.

Comment: might be `server.servlet.context-path`

Comment: are using spring boot or spring MVC with tomcat?

Comment: Spring MVC with Tomcat.

Comment: @Deadpool it seems you were right. The name was somehow registered in the server and it wasn't being updated. I modified the name under "server.xml" under the context tag. It has succesfully changed the url (which was the main issue), although it still shows "new-project-name(original-project-name)" when I'm going to run it. That sort of bugs me. I still wonder where does it take the name from.

Answer (score 0):

Update properties file
/src/main/resources/application.properties

```
server.port=8080
server.contextPath=/original-project-name/
```

/src/main/resources/application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
  contextPath: /original-project-name/
```

Comment: I checked out the server files as suggested by @Deadpool and it modified the url as I desired. Those files you mention did not exist. I have created "application.properties" with the new project name but I'm not so sure about the yml file. Are both necessary?. I still get "new-project-name(original-project-name)" when I'm going to run it and I wonder why.